# Seeding Categories and Subcategories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to seed my database with static categories (e.g. Men's / Women's) then have sub categories which belong to these categories but I actually don't know how to go about doing this with database seeding.

I've got models set up like so:

Category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  has_many :subcategories
  has_many :products ,:through => :subcategories
end
```

Subcategory.rb

```
class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :products
end
```

Product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
  belongs_to :subcategory
end
```

How would I go about writing a database seed to do this?

Comment: `new_category = Category.create( your params)` Then `new_category.subcategories.create( your params )` is what I'm thinking. Not sure exactly so just a comment to get you in the right direction.

Comment: You want seed for test ?

Comment: For testing yes, and for production as usually they won't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind (at least mine) is to create local variables :

```
# db/seeds.rb
mens = Category.create(name: "Men's")
womens = Category.create(name: "Women's")
SubCategory.create(name: 'Slacks', category: mens)
SubCategory.create(name: 'Slacks', category: womens)
```

A nicer (No subcategory can be created apart from its category) solution is to use `Model.create` with a block :

```
Category.create(name: "Men's") do |category|
  Subcategory.create(name: 'Slacks', category: category)
end
```

then seed with the rake task : `$ rake db:seed`